# VSCode adding a new line for every element

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to VsCode and HTML. I have it set to save on format and when I do it automatically places all elements on a new line. First of all, is this good practice? If so that's fine. If not, how do I stop it?

So I type this:

```
<p> My name is <b>Bob</b></p>
```

But it gets formatted to this:

```
<p>
My name is
<b>Bob</b>
</p>
```

Is it good practice to format code like this?

Seems like if the paragraph was really long with multiple elements within it then it could get quite confusing having a bunch of new lines right in the middle of the code.

If not then how do I stop VScode from formatting like this?

I have installed the prettier extension so I am not sure if its VScode or prettier that is actually making these changes.

Any help appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Or don't use any formatter at all, you decide where to put the line break

Comment: You can disable Prettier to see if that is the cause.  I don't think vscode does that by itself.  I also don't think Prettier will do that unless you have the parser set to something other than `html`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in VSC, go to...

**File > Preferences > Settings > Text Editor**

Scroll down until you find:
Auto Indent and change full to none

maybe consider using prettier extension for formatting your code it take the load out of such indentation tasks..

Link to prettier extension [LINK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)